# Raspbian + TP-Link usb wifi drivers

Tags: wifi

I have a TP-LINK TL-WN725N for my RPi, but it doesn't work out of the box. Atleast I can't connect to wifi. I've tried 'Isusb' but don't see it, I don't see my keyboard either though so I might do something wrong.

Can I just drag and drop the drivers to a usb from my windows to the RPi? How do I install it?

Comment: this question is answered here [ http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17187/why-i-obtain-this-error-trying-to-install-tp-link-tl-wn725n-wireless-adapter-d/17188#17188 ]

Comment: I successfully built the driver from source in approx 5 minutes. Check out my answer here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36184/12404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a TP-LINK TL-WN725N for my RPi, but it doesn't work out of the box.

I have a TP-LINK TL-WN725N for my RPi, and it *does* work out of the box.

> I've tried 'lsusb' but don't see it

It will be listed like this:

```
Bus NNN Device NNN: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN
```

Since it identifies itself by chip manufacturer and model number.  Beware that if you plug this dongle in while the pi is running, it will kill the power momentarily -- causing an unclean shutdown and a reboot.  So don't do that, it could lead to grief.  Plug it in before you boot or use a hub.  Unplugging it is okay.

The driver for this is the **8192cu** driver, which should be bundled with the kernel whatever distro you are using.  While it's plugged in, try `lsmod | grep 8192` and you should see it listed.  If so, the dongle has been detected and is ready to use, try `iwconfig` and you should see somewhere in there:

```
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
```

If not, try `modprobe 8192cu` and see what that says (if it says nothing, run `lsmod` again and check).

In my experience, the dongle runs a bit glitchy on the pi -- used on another linux system with the same driver, it's fine, but on the pi it seems to drop the connection occasionally.  Also, on the other system the little blue led inside stays on -- on the pi it blinks.  However, if your software compensates for the occasionally disconnect, it is not noticeable and works fine.

> Atleast I can't connect to wifi.

That's a whole other issue, then.  If you want more specific help, you'll have to post another question explaining what you've tried and where it failed.  It won't happen automatically.

> Can I just drag and drop the drivers to a usb from my windows to the RPi?

Not a chance.  Unfortunately, most manufacturers do not support linux and so other people have to write the drivers, which is why there is not necessarily a perfect one for every device.  WRT the rpi specifically, if you are buying stuff for use with it, check the [verified peripherals page](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals).  The wifi adapters have a page of their own linked in that one, and if you check that page you'll see a couple of (slightly conflicting) reports about the TL-WN725N...I would not trust the one about "manual driver installation" as this person seems to have made an incorrect assumption about what model numbers correlate to what driver.

Comment: In my case I can't find it, but I'm a total linux noob. Now when I do Isusb thats all I write, am I missing something because I get bash: Isusb: command not found. Im doing it in desktop directory if that matters. Before I can start troubleshooting the wifi I need to know the dongle is working.

And about dragging and dropping the drivers I was ofc referring to the working linux drivers, since I have no connection on the pi (not even LAN) that's all I could think about.

Comment: You should be more explicit when you ask a question to save yourself and everyone else some time.  I can't at every point go off for a few paragraphs, "If you meant this..." and/or "If this is such and such..." and/or "To determine whatever..." etc.  That's an *infinite regress*.  In this case you are missing `lsusb`, which is not at all the same thing as saying "lsusb doesn't show whatever" -- lsusb didn't show *anything* because *you didn't have it installed*.  `dpkg -S lsusb` will point you toward `apt-get install usbutils`.

Comment: So by "more explicit" I mean you should post the actual output of a command you feel has failed.  Something I should have asked for to start with, I guess.

Comment: dkpg -S Isusb gave the same "command not found" so I did apt-get.. and I'm not root, how do I get root access? And I know what you mean about giving all details, but I'm such a noob that I don't even know what the details are. Sorry.

Comment: Hmmph -- I would have thought dpkg was part of the core install.  But you can add that with `apt-get install dpkg`.  WRT root access, you can use `sudo` (which may require some configuration to work), or `su`, for which you must know the root password created when you first booted the system.  You can also `exit` (if you are logged in non-remotely) and log in again or just plain `login`, but these require the password too.

Comment: This is strange, 'sudo apt-get install usbutils' says I have the latest version, but 'Isusb' still gives bash: Isusb: command not found. Tried with sudo too. Frustrating.

Comment: Ack! >_< I notice via cut n' paste you are actually using *'I - s - u - s - b'* -- which should be *'l - s - u - s - b'*, difference being the first letter is small L (l), not capital I (I).  Think of `ls` there as an abbreviation for "list", sort of like the plain `ls` command. When in doubt, use serif I guess, lol.

Comment: Hahaha Jesus Christ I've been doing this since yesterday. "is" felt like such a logical command... Okay, now we're getting somewhere :P the wifi dongle shows up on lsusb. lsmod | grep 8192 didn't do anything, not even error. iwconfig says "no wireless extensions".

Comment: I'll close this and start a new question with the info so far.